# Migration to Webpack/ES6 - dependency injection failing

Tags: angular, webpack, dependency-injection, ecmascript-6

As part of a migration to webpack, I must migrate a library, and then change the call to it. I was trying to make minimal changes to the library, to prevent any backward compatibility issue. This is the modified library code:

```
(function() {

  // only added part to the library
  if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
    module.exports = mdPickerColors;
  }
  // end of added part

  angular
    .module('mdColorMenu', ['ngAria', 'ngAnimate', 'ngMaterial'])
    .factory('mdPickerColors', ['$mdColorPalette', '$mdPanel', mdPickerColors])
    .directive('mdColorMenu', mdColorMenuDirective);

  function mdPickerColors($mdColorPalette, $mdPanel) {
    //...
  }
  //...
})();
```

Then in my code, I have an `index.js` that looks like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

import myService from './myService';

import mdPickerColors from 'md-color-menu';

export default angular.module('myModule', [mdPickerColors])
  .service('myService', myService)
  .name;
```

And finally, `myService.js` looks like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';

export default function myService(mdPickerColors, /*...*/) {
  //...
}
```

However, I get the error `Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $mdPanel`. The first dependency (`$mdColorPalette`) is however injected properly.

Additional information:

- I use angular version 1.6.4, angular-material version 1.1.4.
- When I simply import the file in a `<script>` tag, it works as expected.

Any ideas?

Update: I notice that I'm exporting the factory directly, rather than the module. Which means that I'm declaring a factory as a module dependency, which doesn't sound right. Could it be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

I knew this was something stupid. This:

```
if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {
  module.exports = mdPickerColors;
}
```

Should be replaced by:

```
module.exports = angular.module('mdColorMenu').name;
```